How do you express subtyping in multi-sorted equational algebraic theories?
I was told this is achieved with injective functions. Thus, the ordinal numbers can be mapped to a particular set in the type Set. But how do we express which one to map them to?
We only have universal quantification and equality, I believe. (I’m working in Categorical Query Language, writing a typeside.)
I can’t say, “For all x in Nat, there exists an element y : Set such that x = y” because I don’t have existential quantification.
It also would not suffice, since it would not establish an actual value. Say for the ordinal 3 in Nat, it should be mapped to the ordinal set 3 in Set. I can declare the elements as constants of course, but not for every single natural number.
